# Database contents not showing up after render

Tags: python, django, django-views

So, I try to display a list of items from database, but after calling return render(...) it behaves as if there were no objects in the database. I am new to django and after a second day of trial and error I have no idea what to do with it
Affected view:

```
class DropDownList(ListView):
context_object_name = 'drop_down'
template_name="browse.html"
model=ServiceList
asd = ''
def post(self, request):
    name = request.POST.get('selected')
    obj = ServiceList.objects.get(sourceFile=name)
    print(obj)
    print(request.POST) #some prints for debugging
    context = {'asd': obj}
    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Models:

```
class ServiceList(models.Model):
     version = models.IntegerField()
     location = models.CharField(max_length=500)
     services = models.ManyToManyField(Service)
     drms = models.ManyToManyField(Drm)
     sourceFile = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Service(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    locations = models.ManyToManyField(Location)
    names = models.ManyToManyField(Name)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    drm = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

html fragment:

```
        <p>
            <br/>
                <form action="/browse/" id="tableform" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" form="tableform" name="selected">
                        <option selected>-----------------</option>
                        <option >One</option>
                        <option >Two</option>
                        <option >Three</option>
                        {% for obj in drop_down %}
                            <option name={{obj.sourceFile}}>{{obj.sourceFile}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </form>
              <button id="add-list" type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-left" class="button1" form="tableform">+</button>    
        </p>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>UID</th>
                <th>Category</th>
            </tr>
        {% for obj in drop_down %}
        adasdasd
            {% if obj.sourceFile == asd %}
            <br/>fghfghfgh
                {% for service in obj.services.all %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{service.uid}}</td>
                        <td>{{service.category}}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

Comment: Where is drop_down in the context?

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby do I have to pass it in the context to make it work? As I have said, I am new to django

Comment: Templates will only work with what is available in the context

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby can you guide ma a bit? I assume, that I have to add it to context lika I did with asd variable, but how do I use it afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong in your code, I'm going to list them, so it is easier to understand.

1 - `context_object_name = 'drop_down'` is not being used, 'drop_down' is not being declared in your class.

2 - You don't need to assign 'asd' as an empty variable, since you are only using as a namespace for the obj variable in your context set.

3 - Your return function is wrong, you should only be returning the context there, since you are using a class based view.

4 - You are using a ListView to get only one object

I don't know if this is going to work(I don't have a lot of experience in class based views) but try to make your code look like this:

```
class DropDownList(DetailView):
    template_name="browse.html"
    model=ServiceList
    def post(self):
        name = request.POST.get('selected')
        obj = ServiceList.objects.get(sourceFile=name)
        context = {'asd': obj}
        return context
```

you can delete the `context_object_name` line as I mentioned, so if you want to render your ServiceList object version field in and HTML page for example, you should use `{{ asd.version }}`

Also, try to look for function based views, they are better to use, im assuming that you are using this view to get an object from your database, if you were using a function based view here, your code would be much simpler, it would look like this

```
def get_object(request, object_id):
    template = 'browse.html'
    obj = ServiceList.objects.get(pk=object_id)
    context = { 'youcandecideanamehere': obj }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

but you would need to pass the `object_id` parameter in your url(I'm going to create some here, since you didn't give yours)

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('get_object/<object_id>/', get_objects, name='get_objects')
    ...
]
```

And the a tag for that page, should be like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'yourappname:get_objects' obj.id %}"> Text </a>
```

Hope I've helped, but if you still have some problems, feel free to contact me.